# setState getting slower when using setTimeout in a recursion

Tags: reactjs, algorithm

I have been building a maze implementation in React. The basic logic is that every time I run the go function that sets useState with a new 100*100 array by Array.from(),then it checks if its neighbors are available.

This is my maze looks like

[image]

```
  const App: React.FC = () => {
  const Maze: MazeConstructor = MazeData;
  const maze: IMaze = new Maze(mazeJson);
  const [data, setData] = useState(maze.maze);

  const handleClick = (): void => {
    go(maze.entranceX, maze.entranceY);
  }

  const go = (x: number, y: number): void => {
    let timer;
    if (!maze.isInArea(x, y)) throw new Error('x or y is not inside the maze')
    maze.visited![x][y] = true;
    maze.path[x][y] = true;
    maze.maze[x][y] = 1;
    setData(Array.from(maze.maze))
    if (x === maze.exitX && y === maze.exitY) return;
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      let newX = x + direction[i][0];
      let newY = y + direction[i][1];
      if (maze.isInArea(newX, newY) && maze.getCell(newX, newY) === MazeData.ROAD && !maze.visited![newX][newY]) {
       setTimeout(()=>go(newX, newY),50);
      }
    }
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="wrapper">
        {
          data.map((item, index) =>
            // to remove the gap between divs
            <div style={{ fontSize: 0 }}>{
              item.map(i => {
                return <div className={classNames('cell', {
                  'wall': i === '#',
                  'path': i === 1,
                  'road': i === ' ',
                })} />
              }
              )
            }</div>
          )
        }
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Solve</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In order to render the path only once at a time, I added a setTimeout to make it work. Otherwise, the path will be rendered without showing each step. However, I found out that it takes forever to finish the whole rendering. I am just wondering if it is the setTimeout that causes the problem or others. If so, is there any way to fix it of any other alternative to delay the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `setTimeout` you have really changed the algorithm. Instead of the original depth-first search, it has become a breadth-first search.

As you iterate over neighbors, you invoke several `setTimeout` calls, which will be pending in parallel.

Because a call of `go` is scheduled with `setTimeout` without first setting `visited` to true for that cell, you will get situations where `go` will be scheduled to run on the *same* coordinates multiple times.

Also note that you never assign a value to `timer`, making the `clearTimeout` without use. This plan is also is not possible, because you are scheduling several timeouts simultaneously. So even after you have found the target, many timers will continue to timeout and still call `go`.

For introducing the pauses, I would suggest turning `go` into an `async` function, and to do an `await` on a `setTimeout`-based Promise. You would need to step away from recursion and implement an iterative solution instead, which could be based on a stack (so the search order could still be DFS).

Here is how that could look:

```js
// Make function async:
const go = async (x: number, y: number): void => {
    if (!maze.isInArea(x, y)) throw new Error('x or y is not inside the maze')
    let stack = [[x, y]]; // A stack to replace the use of recursion
    while (stack.length) {
        let [x, y] = stack.pop();
        if (maze.visited![x][y]) continue; // Already visited
        maze.visited![x][y] = true;
        maze.path[x][y] = true;
        maze.maze[x][y] = 1;
        setData(Array.from(maze.maze));
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10)); // Await 10ms
        if (x === maze.exitX && y === maze.exitY) return;
        // Reverse the direction of this loop to get the original DFS order
        for (let i = 3; i >= 0; i--) { 
            let newX = x + direction[i][0];
            let newY = y + direction[i][1];
            if (maze.isInArea(newX, newY) && maze.getCell(newX, newY) === MazeData.ROAD 
                                          && !maze.visited![newX][newY]) {
                stack.push([newX, newY]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative of `setTimeout` you could also use:

```
    await new Promise(requestAnimationFrame); // Await next paint
```

The rendering of then thousand `div` elements at each step is quite demanding. A complete redesign where you would have a separate component for each cell, each with its own rendering and state, would improve the performance drastically.

Comment: I just tried your approach out, but it doesn't improve a lot, still getting slower after several iterations

Comment: The main slowdown comes from the rendering of ten thousand `div` elements at each step. This is quite demanding. Instead of `setTimeout`, you can also try `await new Promise(requestAnimationFrame)`, but a really big improvement would be to have separate rendering of each individual cell, and only update the state of the cell that is changing. This requires a complete redesign though.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am considering a redesign. Happy new year!